# Angular, call a function after directive end

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to know when a certain directive has finished its job.

The directive it's not a my directive, it's a directive I use to localize some text; it works very well.

> ref: http://doshprompt.github.io/angular-localization/

Example

```
<p i18n="locale.sampleText"></p>
```

I need to know when the `sampleText` is injected into the `p` element becouse this changes the size of the `p` and I need to update my layout.

Thanks.

Comment: What does `update my layout` mean?  There isn't a simple and inexpensive way to do what you are asking

Comment: In simple words, "update my layout" means that I need to know the element height.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a directive post link function. This function will be called at the end of the elements processing - so the text should already been translated at the time. See also http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/07/07/practical-guide-to-prelink-postlink-and-controller-methods-of-angular-directives/

```
<p i18n="locale.sampleText" post-process></p>

app.directive('postProcess', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: {
          post: function(scope,elem,attr){
              $timeout(function() {
                  doPostProcess();
              });
          }    
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: this does not guarantee the other directive has completed. Also,default for `link` is the post link so not necessary to add extra property if not using `pre`

Comment: right - the `postProcess` would need to be defined on the parent element. But that probably won't work in that use-case either. You need to wait until the DOM has been updated to get the correct height. So a solution is to use `$timeout` to postpone the process after the DOM has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not a proper way to solve your problem** but you can done your job by writing a directive

```
<p i18n="locale.sampleText" check-content-loaded></p>
```

The directive looks like

```
myModule.directive('checkContentLoaded', function ($interval) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    var interval = $interval(function () {
                        console.log('still not found');
                        if (element.text()) {
                            $interval.cancel(interval);
                            console.log('found'); //here you can change your layout
                        };
                    }, 1000); //changing time interval you can improve performance
                }
            };
        });
```